# jQuery effects are not working - on Ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is one of the codes:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    if (message == '') {
        $('#incorrmess').html('<img src = "wrong.png"/> Please type in your message').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        //Ajax statement
    }
});
```

And on the body of the page, I have the div. The effects are not working. 
I also tried this:

```
$('#incorrmess').slideDown("slow").html('<img src = "wrong.png"/> Please type in your message');
```

What do I do to make the effects work?

Thanks.

Comment: what JS error did you have? Could you post it here? It'd also be nice if you could create jsFiddle with your minimal html and jquery code

Comment: PLease can you check on console of your browser if there are some errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first hide, and then slideDown. slideDown on a visible element won't do anything.

`$('#incorrmess').hide().html('<img src = "wrong.png"/> Please type in your message').slideDown("slow");`

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the div `incorrmess` as `display:none;` and then try with `$('#incorrmess').html('<img src = "wrong.png"/> Please type in your message').slideDown("slow");`. Also check out this simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8dvEn/1/)